# Hide Mobile Video Play Button

Tags: html5-video, video.js

Is there a way to hide the default play button in ios/android mobile devices for HTML video?

I am using video.js with the following html

```
<video id="battery_video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered"
          controls preload="auto" width="720" height="480"
          poster="/videoLibrary/data/thumbnails/Battery.jpg"
          data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
         <source src="/videoLibrary/data/video/Battery.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
        </video>
```

Things look like I want on the desktop browsers but ios/android are dropping a play button in.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time it doesn't look like there's a way to hide the play button.

Answer (score 0):

videoplayer.bigPlayButton.hide();